# How can I convert dataset property names to data attribute names?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have an object with some keys and values, intended to be assigned to the `dataset` property of an HTML element. I would like to get the names of the [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) that would be produced from those keys, as described where it says "camelCase to dash-style" in the "Name Conversion" section of the [MDN dataset documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).

**How can I convert from dataset property names to data attribute names?** I came up with something that works, which I put in an answer, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler or more elegant way, maybe involving a built-in function that I somehow overlooked.

I am looking for either a function that converts an individual name, or a function that converts an object with key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

My function for converting an individual name:

```
const dataAttributeFromDatasetProperty = attr =>
    `data-${attr.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `-${letter.toLowerCase()}`)}`;
```

My function for converting an object:

```
const dataAttributesFromDataset = dataset =>
    _.mapKeys(
        dataset,
        (value, attr) => `data-${attr.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `-${letter.toLowerCase()}`)}`
    );
```

It uses lodash's [`_.mapKeys`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapKeys) function.

Answer (score -1):

I mean, theoretically you could just get the `.outerHTML` and grab the data tags off of it that way.

```js
var test = document.createElement('span');

test.dataset.myTestDataElement = 'weee';
test.dataset.mySecondThing = 'data-test do not match me';

var html = test.outerHTML;

html.replace(/(data-[^=]+)=/g, function(_, name, _, _){
  console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... parsing the HTML seems even harder and more error-prone than what I'm doing. But I like the idea. Maybe I can get the attributes using `test.attributes` and pick out the data attributes.

Comment: A regex finder for starts with `data-` isn't that difficult

Comment: OK, but what if I do something like `test.dataset.myTestDataElement = 'data-something'`?

Comment: Updated to include an attempt at regex logic to find the names.  Also added your test issue of the value matching the syntax of a data attribute. @EliasZamaria

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `replace` call? Calling it just for the side effects of the callback passed to it, and throwing away the string it returns? Maybe `match` would be better, but the approach of using a regex to parse HTML seems fragile to me.

Comment: Obligatory comment about using regexes to parse HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/28324

Comment: *shrug* Up to you.  I'm just offering the suggestion.

Comment: OK. Sorry if I sounded snarky. I felt that if I didn't link to that famous HTML-parsing regex post, someone else would have done it.

Comment: Nah, it's all good.  I did put "theoretically" in my original answer for a reason, :)